# how to construct a boolean algebra out of a set of well formed formulas?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Given a set of well formed formulas of a first order language (with equality, constants, variables, non-logical symbols, etc), is it possible to use it as some kind of base to construct a (possible complete) boolean algebra? I guess it would be problematic if I only say that $\vee$ is the sum, $\neg$ gives the inverse, etc, I think it would be necessary to take equivalence classes, for example, 1 would represent the class of the tautologies (or more, I don't really know). I want to know how can I possibly do that, if it is possible at all. If what I'm asking is too general, just take the standard language of set theory (but I would like to make this construction in the most general way).

Comment: What is a non-logical symbol?

Comment: Logical symbols are, for example, $\vee$, $\wedge$, $\rightarrow$, etc. Non-logical symbols can be anything else, for example, $+$, $\in$, $\cup$, $\exp$, $\sup$, $\int$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard construction known as the [Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra).  Given a theory $T$ in a first-order language $L$ (you can take $T$ to be the empty theory if you like), impose an equivalence relation $\sim$ on sentences in $L$ by saying $\varphi\sim\psi$ iff $T\vdash \varphi\Leftrightarrow\psi$.  The set $B$ of equivalence classes of sentences then forms a Boolean algebra, with $[\varphi]\vee[\psi]=[\varphi\vee\psi]$, $[\varphi]\wedge[\psi]=[\varphi\wedge \psi]$, and $\neg[\varphi]=[\neg\varphi]$.

Comment: this construction seems to concern only propositional logic, what can I do with predicates and quantified formulas such as $(\forall x)(\exists y)(\exists z)(\varphi(x,y)\rightarrow (\forall w)(\psi(w)\rightarrow \xi (x,z)))$?

Comment: Well, such sentences are still a part of the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra, but you are right that the quantifiers have no meaning in the algebra structure.  But I don't know how you could make them part of the algebra structure.  The problem is that formulas with free variables have fundamentally different sorts of "truth values" than sentences (because their truth depends on a choice of interpretation of the free variables).

Comment: A quantifier is really a map (though not a homomorphism) between two _different_ Lindenbaum-Tarski algebras: the domain is the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of the language with an extra constant symbol added (for the variable you are quantifying over), and the codomain is the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of the original language.

Comment: My intention with this construction is the following: given the set of wff, define a boolean algebra wff/~ such that it would provide a boolean valued structure on itself and, with that, given a complete theory T, T/~ would be an ultrafilter and its characteristic function would be an interpretation for a model of T. Does it makes sense? Is it possible? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you restrict your formulas to _sentences_, then the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra does almost what you're asking for: a complete theory (extending the base theory you used to define the algebra) is the same thing as an ultrafilter on the algebra.  But you aren't going to be able to construct a model of $T$ from this unless you do some sort of Henkin construction adding a bunch of constants to your language to witness every existential statement.